# The positive integer n for which (int_(0)^(n)(g(x)−f(x))dx=100 is?

Tags: calculus, functions

On the real line R, we define two functions f and g as follows:
f(x)=min[x−[x],1−x+[x]],
g(x)=max[x−[x],1−x+[x]],
where [x] denotes the largest integer not exceeding x.

Below is one of the solution I found but I could not get it :

[image: it is one of the solution I found but I could not get it]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You are *overloading* the $[...]$ operator.  For example, I surmise that you intended that $f(x) = \min\left(x - [x], 1 - x + [x]\right)$.  One way to avoid this is use the $\lfloor x\rfloor$ operator (i.e. `$\lfloor x\rfloor$`) rather than the [x] operator to denote largest integer $\leq x$.

Comment: To attack the problem, first attempt to evaluate $$\int_0^1 ( ~g(x) - f(x) ~) dx = \left\{\int_0^{1/2} ( ~g(x) - f(x) ~) dx\right\} + \left\{\int_{1/2}^1 ( ~g(x) - f(x) ~) dx\right\}.$$ Then, compare (for example) $$\int_0^1 ( ~g(x) - f(x) ~) dx ~~\text{against} ~~\int_1^2 ( ~g(x) - f(x) ~) dx.$$